# Three randomly placed points inside a unit circle. Probability that the formed triangle contains the centre of the circle inside?

Tags: probability, triangles, circles

Three non-collinear points are placed randomly inside a unit circle.

**Question:** What is the probability that if you were to connect these points, forming a triangle, the triangle will have the center of the circle contained inside (including the periferi)?

Here are two examples, A and B, illustrating what I mean:

[image]

where you can see that A works and B doesn't work.

---

What Iv'e tried so far is illustarated in the following image:

[image]

Two randomly points are obviously always collinear. So we can connect the two. Now let's draw a staright line, starting from each point, through the center and finish on the circumference of the circle. The grey shaded area represents the region where the third point needs to be in order to create a triangle that works.
Now, as you can see there can be all kinds of regions depending on where the first two points are located. So I'm simply looking for a method/approach that can answer this question. If you have a another approach than my example feel free to use it. I'm not sure if this is very complicated or if there is a nice solution.

Comment: It may well depend on what your random procedure is - have you seen this about choosing random chords of a circle? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)

Comment: @MarkBennet I haven't seen that, no. But how can we make this problem more well-defined so that we can reach to an answer?

Comment: @MarkBennet I can edit the post accordingly, if there is a way to make it more well definied.

Comment: It is just that different approaches may give different results - I hope you get some interesting answers.

Comment: There is no ambiguity here such as in Bertrand's paradox right ? (Assuming "placed randomly" means independently and uniformly)

Comment: You say there can be all kinds of regions (where the third point needs to be). I only see one kind: a circular sector. Its area is easy to find.

Comment: @nicomezi Yes, independently and uniformly.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I meant all kind of different sectors. Given that the size of the sectors varies depending of the locations of the two point.

Comment: Sure, but isn't the dependence obvious to the point of being trivial?

Comment: @IvanNeretin I don't see what's trivial here... you mean to calculate the probability I'm looking for?

Comment: @IvanNeretin How to take into consideration of that dependence to calculate the probability is what I can't figure out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say the points are $p_1, p_2$ and $p_3$.  To simplify discussion, let's also choose coordinates so that the center of the circle is at the origin and $p_1$ is on the positive $x$ axis, somewhere between $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$.  With these coordinates, triangle $p_1 p_2 p_3$ encloses the origin if and only if (1) $p_2$ and $p_3$ lie on opposite sides of the $x$ axis, and (2) the line $p_2 p_3$ intersects the negative portion of the $x$ axis.

By symmetry, $p_2$ lies in the upper half plane with probability $1/2$ and in the lower half plane with probability $1/2$.  The same is true of $p_3$, so the probability that $p_2$ and $p_3$ lie on opposite sides of the $x$ axis is $1/2$.

Again by symmetry, line $p_2 p_3$ intersects the positive $x$ axis with probability $1/2$ and the negative $x$ axis with probability $1/2$.

Conditions (1) and (2) are independent in probability, so the probability that both hold is
$$\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: You have to postulate that the distribution of $p_i$ is invariant by rotation. Up to this this is a very good answer.

Comment: @GérardLetac I admit to a certain amount of hand-waving. :-)

Comment: Great answer based on a simple idea!  These are the type of answers I'm looking for since my level of math isn't as advanced like most in here. Check mark is yours :)

Answer (score 1):

I presume that your points are distributed *uniformly* in the interior of the circle.

1. Observe than only the angular coordinates matter, but radial don't. Your points could just as well have been uniformly distributed over the *circumference*.
2. Now we define a function ($\chi$) which equals 1 when the triangle is good and 0 when it is bad, and integrate it over all possible positions of the three points: $0\leqslant\varphi_1,\varphi_2,\varphi_3<2\pi$.
3. When we fix $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$, the integral over $\varphi_3$ is the arc length of your grey sector. It only depends on $\varphi_2-\varphi_1$: when this difference is less than $\pi$, this is just it, and when greater, this is its complement to $2\pi$.
4. Observe that $\varphi_1$ does not matter at all because of the circular symmetry of the problem. The first point could just as well always sit at $\varphi_1=0$.
5. Now integrate over the remaining variables:
   $$\iint\chi(\varphi_2,\varphi_3)\rho(\varphi_2)\rho(\varphi_3)d\varphi_2d\varphi_3 = \\
   = \left({1\over2\pi}\right)^2\left(\int_0^{\pi}\varphi_2d\varphi_2+\int_\pi^{2\pi}(2\pi-\varphi_2)d\varphi_2\right) = \\
   = {1\over4\pi^2}\left(\frac12\pi^2+\frac12\pi^2\right)=\frac14$$
   So it goes.

Comment: I don't doubt you're correct but I just can't follow everything since my level of math isn't advanced. The other answer is based on a really simple idea with the same answer as yours so for that reason they get the check mark.

Comment: I agree, the other answer is simpler and thus better.